# Detect if user selects all text in input and deletes it, in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using onKeyUp or onKeyDown, is it possible to detect if the user has selected all the text within and input and deleted it?

Here's a rough overview of the code I have (simplified):

```
handleChange = (event) => {
   const value = event.target.value;
   const keyCode = event.keyCode;
   this.setState({ searchValue: value })
   // This triggers a dispatch of a redux action
   this.props.handleChange(this.props.tagsId, this.state.searchValue, keyCode);
}

<input
   placeholder="Search"
   type="text"
   onKeyUp={ this.handleChange }
/>
```

When I inspect the incoming values within my redux implementation, I never see `this.state.searchValue` as an empty string, basically the `handleChange` method passes at a minimum a single character. When you select and delete all the text in the input, the `this.state.searchValue` equals the entire string deleted. How can I track deleting the entirety of the text within the input?

Comment: Would the `onChange` event fit your use case, or does it have to be either `onKeyUp` or `onKeyDown`?

Comment: `OnKeyUp` or something similar would be ideal, to have access to `keyCode`.